# How to send RJSON request using jquery

Tags: jquery, request, compression, rjson

I have found lot of articles showing solutions to compress JSON string but none seem to explain the procedure for sending this compressed JSON string as a request via JQuery. 
The article at https://github.com/dogada/RJSON shows one of the ways to compress JSON string (also known as RJSON).
Has anyone ever succeeded sending RJSON as request using jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I can pass it as form encoded request and have a custom handler on the server to handle that request. I didn't knew it was that easy